# I can not get a new javascript element to appear within a div

Tags: javascript, html

New to javascript and can't find my answer anywhere else.

Within a DIV section, I push a button that makes an image appear. My problem is that the image always appears at the very left of the screen.

```
<div id="rightcolumn">      
    <input type="button" value="B&B" onclick="createImage();"/> 
    <script>
        function createImage()enter code here
        {
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            var s = document.createElement("input");
            s.src = "C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\Website\\Images\\greysquare.png";
            s.type = "image";
            body.appendChild(s);
        }
    </script
</div>
```

1) How do I make the new image appear within the div tag instead of on the very left of the page?

2) They always appear next to each other horizontally. I want the images to appear stacked on top of each other when they are made. How do I do this?

Comment: @jfriend00 I mean, technically `<input type="image" />` takes a `src` attribute, but they aren't even showing that in the code so you're probably right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append it to the `div` element instead of the body:

```
var rightColumn = document.getElementById('rightcolumn');
rightColumn.appendChild(s);
```

(Also, why are you using `input` instead of `img`?). As for the positioning of the element, the right way to position it would be to use CSS (add a class to the element by setting its className property, and then include CSS in your HTML page that styles that class appropriately).

Comment: If I add two images, they stack on top of each other. How do I get them separate? Is that a css thing or do I do it in the Javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by "separate"? Generally, though, the answer is yes -- you use CSS to control the positioning and display of elements. If you want them to be positioned in some other way (like next to each other horizontally), then you would use CSS to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

you should append the new element `image` to the `DIV` not body

```
 var div=document.getElementById("rightcolumn");
 div.appendChild(s);
```